# How to get decimal value of weight in mini cart?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7, mini-cart

How to get decimal value of weight in `mini cart`.
I need to display only **2** decimals `11.00` instead of `11.0000`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you want weight value as like 11.00, right ?

Comment: yeah its script had written in knockoutjs  Aditya Shah

Comment: Can you please add your phtml & js file code here ?

Comment: <strong class="product-item-Weight">
                <!-- ko if: weight -->
                <div class="Approx-Weight" data-bind="html: 'Approx Weight : ' + weight * qty "></div>
                <!-- /ko -->
          </strong>

Comment: Code is in .html file  Rohan Hapan

Comment: @RohanHapani i was just thinking to tag you here :D for giving an answer, because i saw some post where you have gave solution kind of like this :)

Comment: Yeah :D But, it's knockout. So, It's different que than I gave all answer.

Comment: @trilokkumar please check my answer and let me know if still not solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that, You need to **add one custom function** and **pass your precision value and weight value**. Add this below code in your html file :

```
<strong class="product-item-Weight">
<!-- ko if: weight -->
    <div class="Approx-Weight" data-bind="html: 'Approx Weight : ' + getWeight(2,weight * qty) ">
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
</strong>
```

Now, **create getWeight() function** in your knockout file **inside Component.extend** :

```
getWeight : function(precision,WeightValue){
    var self = this;
    return WeightValue / Math.pow(10, self.precision());
},
```

Now, **refresh your html and knockout js file and check it.**

Hope, It maybe helpful for you.

Comment: Where should i  create getWeight() function in your knockout file inside Component.extend  Rohan Hapani

Comment: You can add anywhere inside Component.extend. It should be like this : return Component.extend({
            defaults:{
               ...........
            },
            getWeight : function(precision,WeightValue){
                return WeightValue / Math.pow(10, self.precision());
            },
            ..............
});

Comment: Happy to help :) Happy Coding !!

Comment: Its not working for me Rohan Hapani

Comment: Any error or log or console error? Please check it that html and js changes apply or not.

Comment: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return weight }"
Message: Unable to process binding "html: function(){return 'Approx Weight66 : '+ getWeight(2,weight * qty) }"
Message: getWeight is not defined error  Rohan Hapani

Comment: Please add whole js code and update question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84476/discussion-between-trilok-kumar-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `number_format` function like this in minicart template file-

```
number_format($weight, 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: script had written in knockoutjs Shashank Kumrawat

Answer (score 1):

**JS:**

```
var value = 11.0000;
var result = value.toFixed(2); 
alert(result); // 11.00
```

**PHP:**

```
$value  = "11.0000";
$result = bcadd($value , 0, 2);

echo $result ; // 11.00
```

**Update:**

You can create a block, you put your js inside, then you bind that block in your `knockoutjs`

```
1. <?php $jsBlock = echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("html/custom.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var js_block = <?php echo json_encode($jsBlock)?>;
</script>
2. web/template/somename.html
<div class="name-class" data-bind="html:js_block"></div> 

3. custom.phtml 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = 11.0000;
    var result = value.toFixed(2); 
    alert(result); // 11.00
</script>
```

**Update2:**

1. > app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

   ```
   <?php $jsBlock = echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("html/custom.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       var js_block = <?php echo json_encode($jsBlock)?>;
   </script>
   ```
2. > web/template/somename.html

   ```
   <div class="name-class" data-bind="html:js_block"></div>
   ```

Comment: script had written in knockoutjs PRINCE

Comment: Check my update, I don't tested it but I think it should work

Comment: web/template/somename.html my file location 
<div class="name-class" data-bind="html:js_block"></div>  here how to get PRINCE

Comment: Look my update2

Comment: I am not getting any value as update2 – PRINCE