# How to display a specific attribute in the cart in magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

In my case my demand is to display the weight for the product also like the name, the quantity ..., in the mini cart but I can't find a proper way to display the weight, can anyone tell me how please :

this is the code that is responsible for displaying data in the cart

File location :

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

The code :

```
<div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <strong class="product-item-name">
                            <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                            <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                            <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </strong>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: try this link : - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224260/add-custom-product-attribute-to-mini-cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, You need to `add one custom function` and `pass your precision value and weight value`. Add this below code in your html file :

```
<strong class="product-item-Weight">
<!-- ko if: weight -->
    <div class="Approx-Weight" data-bind="html: 'Approx Weight : ' + getWeight(2,weight * qty) ">
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
</strong>
```

Now, create `getWeight() function` in your knockout file `inside Component.extend` :

```
getWeight : function(precision,WeightValue){
    var self = this;
    return WeightValue / Math.pow(10, self.precision());
},
```

Now, refresh your html and knockout js file and check it.

And More refer this :-

[How to get decimal value of weight in mini cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/246449/how-to-get-decimal-value-of-weight-in-mini-cart)

Thanks...